# Is it normal for compiz on Ubuntu 16.04 to consume 60+% of my CPU with no other programs running?

Tags: 16.04, compiz, cpu

Is it normal for compiz to consume 60%+ of my CPU with no other programs running?
I simply just installed Ubuntu, and that's what I got.

Comment: Normal is very relative, but if you thing the computer resource usage is too high, try to enable the low graphics mode, or switch to mate or xfce.